# Override Methods in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, function, overriding

I have the following situation:

```
abstract class A implements OnInit{

    ngOnInit() {
        this.method();
    }

    private method() {
        // doing stuff
    }
}

class B extends class A implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
         this.method(); // B version
    }

    method() {
        // Do different stuff from A
    }
}
```

I know a possible solution would be to make method() in class A public, but it in a library I cannot edit.
In my B component I need to do a custom version of method() and prevent the A version from happening.

How could this be achieved?

Comment: if you don't want use `public`use `protected`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is

Comment: The issue is that I can't edit the library code. I already use it out-of-the-box in many other components because the default behaviour is correct, but in this particular one it is not. It is in a shared library that a co-working company uses and if I modify it, their code might break.

Answer (score 0):

If you use abstract class, your method should be abstract and shall not have any implementation.

Use abstract class as follows (https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/abstract-class)

```
abstract class Person {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    display(): void{
        console.log(this.name);
    }

    abstract find(string): Person;
}

class Employee extends Person { 
    empCode: number;

    constructor(name: string, code: number) { 
        super(name); // must call super()
        this.empCode = code;
    }

    find(name:string): Person { 
        // execute AJAX request to find an employee from a db
        return new Employee(name, 1);
    }
}

let emp: Person = new Employee("James", 100);
emp.display(); //James

let emp2: Person = emp.find('Steve');
```

Or, If you do want to implement the method in class A, you can use a regular class as follows (https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-class)

```
class Car {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    run(speed:number = 0) {
        console.log("A " + this.name + " is moving at " + speed + " mph!");
    }
}

class Mercedes extends Car {

    constructor(name: string) {
        super(name);
    }

    run(speed = 150) {
        console.log('A Mercedes started')
        super.run(speed);
    }
}

class Honda extends Car {

    constructor(name: string) {
        super(name);
    }

    run(speed = 100) {
        console.log('A Honda started')
        super.run(speed);
    }
}

let mercObj = new Mercedes("Mercedes-Benz GLA");
let hondaObj = new Honda("Honda City")

mercObj.run();  // A Mercedes started A Mercedes-Benz GLA is moving at 150 mph!
hondaObj.run(); // A Honda started A Honda City is moving at 100 mph!
```

Comment: Sadly class A is "untouchable", it is part of a framework of a co-working company and I'm not allowed to modify it since it's a shared project.